# Big black box on filterable searchview

Tags: android, listview, search, searchview, toast

I am following this tutorial and I see a big black box on filterable searchview. Almost like a toast. Any idea what it is and how to get rid of it? I searched the developer docs and could not find any info on it. When I remove parts of the onQueryTextChange, it stops filtering altogether. Many kind regards

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/06/01/create-searchview-filter-mode-listview-android/

[image]

See code:

```
    SearchView search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    final String[] mStrings = {"1", "2", "text", "more text", "more text here"};

    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStrings));
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    setupSearchView();
```

...

```
private void setupSearchView() {
    search.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    search.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
    search.setQueryHint("Search Here");
}

public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        list.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        list.setFilterText(newText.toString());

    }
    return true;
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you please update your post to include your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);` to `list.setTextFilterEnabled(false);`.

Also change your `onQueryTextChange` to the below:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    CustomAdapter customAdapter = (customAdapter)list.getAdapter();
    Filter filter = customAdapter.getFilter();


    filter.filter(newText);
    return true;
}
```

According to [Google](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setTextFilterEnabled%28boolean%29),

> `setTextFilterEnabled` Enables or disables the type filter window. If enabled, typing when this view has focus will filter the children to match the users input.

Comment: unfortunately, changing this to false will render the whole list unfilterable. I am just trying to remove the big black box (as seen in the snip with the text 'AB').

Comment: Please check my revised post.

Comment: Awesome! Looks like casting a separate filter worked!

Comment: Hii @DrewSzurko

I have also having same issue as above mention and i have tried your solution too , but now the list update only when i add text in search view and click on search button , it will not perform searching based on character enters..

Need help to resolve this 
Help will be appreciated .
Thanks in advance